# hrtimer_nanosleep explanation

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls, sleep

I have searched the Internet and did not find any explanation for `hrtimer_nanosleep`. What is the usage of this function and how does it differ from the `clock_nanosleep` API?

Can someone please explain or point out to any links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`clock_nanosleep`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_nanosleep.2.html) is a system call, *i.e.* an API made available by the kernel to user space. You’ll find it defined [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.3.8/source/kernel/time/posix-timers.c#L1173).

`clock_nanosleep` relies on [a number of clock definitions](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.3.8/source/kernel/time/posix-timers.c#L1227), in particular on the `nsleep` entry in those structures. This points to [`common_nsleep`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.3.8/source/kernel/time/posix-timers.c#L1165) which is a wrapper around [`hrtimer_nanosleep`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.3.8/source/kernel/time/hrtimer.c#L1719).

That’s the relationship between the two: `clock_nanosleep` is a system call, and `hrtimer_nanosleep` is the internal kernel function used to implement it. You can’t call the latter from outside the kernel, only the former.

`hrtimer_nanosleep` is also used to implement other system calls, for example [`nanosleep`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.3.8/source/kernel/time/hrtimer.c#L1754).